# Using XML in HTML page without using a server

Tags: javascript, css, xml, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to use XML in HTML pages and retrieve the information using javascript from the XML files?

I'm asking it because I don't have a server and I'm using an HTA.
I want the XML to contain data and that it will be easy to modify and update if necesary.

I tried using xmlhttprequest and it's not working without a server of course..

I thought using this XML pages as the main page and only use CSS to design it, but it seems to be even uglier than just using a normal HTML page.

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing XML to HTML Without a Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586891/importing-xml-to-html-without-a-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is run entirely via your web browser, so there is no need for a server side technology (such as php, Coldfusion, .NET, etc).

If you store a copy of jquery locally, and load it, you can do some pretty fancy XML manipulation:
http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/

It sounds like you might be wanting to do an XSLT Transform (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt). This can also be done within a web browser without any server to run upon.

Comment: I tried downloading the example in the end of the page (XML.ZIP), it is not working localy ( under IE 8. Is the IE version matters? ), On the online web example (The same as I downloaded) it is working fine.

Comment: When you are experimenting with Javscript, I would highly recommend using Firebug ( http://getfirebug.com/ ) with Firefox. At least you can get some diagnostics about what parts are specifically generating errors. Most other browsers have some kind of dev tools, but I prefer firebug. Another example: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The only browser I know of that allows you to do so was IE with [XML Data Islands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766512%28VS.85%29.aspx), this was with IE 5 and worked with IE 6, though I don't know if later versions have this feature.

However, you can emulate these with the DOM - see [this](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XML_Data_Island) wiki page.