# AJAX Code Ignored #Irrelevant

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, html

When attempting to use the following code:

```
<script src="lib/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
function readXML()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
              url: "myXML.xml",
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "xml",
              success: function(xml){
                    alert(xml);
              }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

for some reason the code is ignored entirely. When I used the alert() before $.ajax it worked, but for some reason the entire AJAX code within is ignored. Other types of jQuery codes don't work, either. The rest of the code works perfectly fine - everything that has nothing to do with AJAX or jQuery. What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I try adding "complete" or "error" the entire page wouldn't load. When I replace success with done/error I get the exact same result - the code is ignored entirely. I know I'm doing something wrong, but having tried an awful lot of codes from here, I have no idea what else to do. Help?

UPDATE:

error finally did work and got me this result:

"NetworkError: failed to execute send on XMLHttpRequest: failed to load file myXML.xml"

However, I read that's the only way to import xml without loading everything to a server here: [Using XML in HTML page without using a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379901/using-xml-in-html-page-without-using-a-server)

What am I missing?

Comment: Firstly having a DOMReady handler inside a function is redundant. Secondly, if the `success` handler is not called then logically there is an error with the request. You need to check the network tab of the console, and/or add an `error` handler and check it's properties to discover what the issue is.

Comment: You defined the readXML() function but I don't see you calling it anywhere.

Comment: @Grasshopper I thought the same, however OP does state that an `alert()` within the function does work, so it must be being called from somewhere else in code that was not included in the question.

Comment: Maybe show us a little bit more of the code.

Comment: Anyway, a DOMReady handler inside a function is a nonsense.

Comment: _Other types of jQuery codes don't work, either_ is jQuery really loaded on to the page? try alerting `typeof jQuery` and see what it shows up.

Comment: @Grasshopper It's irrelevant. The function is being called and responds perfectly fine until it reaches the jQuery - which it skips - and moves on normally.

Comment: @LShetty Will try that as soon as I'm at home, but the weird thing is when I try the test code from w3schools it works, and then as soon as I try using the same library for something else it doesn't...

Comment: The code you're showing would work unless $ is not defined. If you run it with any js dev tools enabled (FF+firebug, Chrome Dev Tools or any of the kind), a reference to an undefined $ must show up in the console. You might try wrapping the ajax call in a try catch statement and printing the exception.

Comment: @Grasshopper Not sure I'm using any, but how do I write that?

Comment: FF -> Shift + F5 or install Firebug Extension. Chrome -> Ctrl+Shift+I.

Comment: @AnnCarter does the xml exist at the root of your project?

Comment: @imGreg Yup. Both are in the same location.

Comment: @Grasshopper Okay, I switched back to 2.0.3 and got two errors: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". How do I fix it?

Comment: Check the path of your jquery  and the $ error is because jquery wasnt loaded yet.

Comment: @imGreg Saved the jQuery file locally and this is what I get... XMLHttpRequest cannot load myXML.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send @ jquery-2.0.3.js:7848
jquery-2.0.3.js:7311 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'myXML.xml'.

Comment: @AnnCarter — That's self-explanatory. You need to use HTTP (which means you need a webserver). You can't do Ajax on local files.

Comment: @Quentin Then how does it work here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379901/using-xml-in-html-page-without-using-a-server ?

Comment: @AnnCarter — It doesn't. the OP's comment on the accepted answer even says that.

Comment: @Quentin Weird, because he marked it as helpful. I suppose I should lock this thing and ask a new question, then.