# Importing XML to HTML Without a Server

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I've been trying to import an XML document into HTML without using a server. I'm working with standalone computers so I can't upload it to any server, which means I can't use XMLHttpRequest. I found a thread here saying I could use jQuery AJAX, but as it turns out, I can't use that either. Does anybody know a way I could do it without copying the entire XML into the JS code?

To requests, here's what I need to do with it: Basically the XML contains questions from which I want to create a test. Now, the test doesn't include all the questions, so I'm using JS to pick random questions and place them in the HTML document. I don't want to copy the entire XML to the script file because it looks really unprofessional and I want to keep it as simple as possible.

At this point I'm really willing to try anything, including JSON, if that makes it easier. I just need the ability to use JS on the data and the ability to write it in the HTML document.

Comment: Not quite the answer you want, but if your data is transformed into a JavaScript or JSON file you can just include it with a `<script src="..."></script>` tag.

Comment: look at this http://onlinemca.com/mca_course/kurukshetra_university/semester5/webengineering/xml_embedding_into_html.php

Comment: @Alex: That's inlined and does not load from a second file, though.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without javascript. You need it

Comment: @AnnCarter: Are you fine with copying it into HTML somewhere else (not into the JS code)? Then you can look it up from JS code by `document.getElementId('myXML')`.  http://ajaxpatterns.org/XML_Data_Island

Comment: @scunliffe If I turn it into a JSON file I can load it just like that? How do I use it, though?

Comment: @Thilo XMLDataIslands (at least the ones Microsoft invented in Internet Explorer) are a really bad concept that has now been completely deprecated and removed from IE. I would avoid like the plague.

Comment: @AnnCarter I added an answer explaining how you could use a JavaScript/JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to include the question file as JavaScript content (still in a separate file) instead.

If the content is really simple (eg just a list) then your file could just be a simple array.

```
var questions = [
  "What time is it?",
  "Is the sky blue?",
  "What do you call a fish with no legs?"
];
```

You just include this file in your page with a script tag:

```
<script src="questions.js"></script>
```

If your question structure is more complicated you can include it in a JSON format that allows for complex nesting etc.

```
var questions = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "question":"What time is it?",
    "datatype":"text"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "question":"Is the sky blue?",
    "datatype":"boolean"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "question":"What do you call a fish with no legs?",
    "datatype":"text"
  }
];
```

Either way once the question data is loaded into memory you can randomize the questions and decide which ones to render.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can run a local server on your stand alone computer. There are many to choose from, just google. That is what localhost is for. ie http://127.0.0.1/some_xml_file.xml

Comment: If I use a local server, do I use the XMLHttpRequest? And also, if I later want to copy it to an inner network where I work, say, would it still work (with proper IP, of course)?

Comment: yes you can use XMLHttpRequest, and yes it will work later on a network server with a real ip.

Comment: I tried doing it (placing both files on the desktop) and opening it, but the console reads XMLHttpRequest Exception 101. What do I do with that?

Comment: Youve got to run a server on your pc, for local use and request the document from 127.0.0.1. ( The internal ip for a machine to refer to itself.)

Comment: Okay... How do I do that?

Comment: Is there any way to do it without creating a server?

Comment: Well, if you can change format to javascript as scunliffe is suggesting, then that's the way to do it. But if you stick with XML - you'll need a server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to transform an XML document into HTML the shortest path is to use XSLT (EXtensible Stylesheet Language).  This involves defining an additional XSLT document which describes how your XML should be transformed and the output can be HTML should you choose.  One introduction to XSLT is here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/.

Most people will resort to JavaScript, but that's a deeper rabbit hole IMHO.